# How to Add NULL into SQL Report

Tags: sql, null, report, addition

Okay this is hard to explain but I will try my best. So I am building a report through report builder. The report is to show the funded dates and cancel dates of each report depending upon which date the user wishes to input. So the parameters are @BeginDate and @EndDate as well as a third parameter which is a dropdown for the company they pick. The codec is fine and I can see the reports just fine. But when I tested the report I found that there are 3 NULLS on an account for the cancel date but the funded date account is fine. So the error I am having is in the funded report there are 3 accounts which the funded account does not show because the cancel date is NULL. All other accounts show up fine except 3. This is my codec In MS SQL SERVER 2008. I am using a stored Procedure. If you need more detail I will provide it to you for more clarity.

```
ALTER PROC [dbo].[spAdminFundedDate]
    (@Beginning_Date  DATETIME, 
     @Ending_Date DATETIME,
     @program int=null)

As
    Begin
        SELECT  @program, c.program_id, d.dealer_code,b.last_name As DealerName,
                a.account_no, a.vin, ((e.last_name)+','+(e.first_name)) As Name, 
                a.funded_date, a.cancel_refund_date, a.purchase_date,a.miles,
                a.duration,a.sale_price,a.number_of_payments, a.sales_tax, a.downpayment
        FROM tDealer d 
        JOIN tContact b ON d.contact_id = b.contact_id 
        JOIN tContract a On d.dealer_id = a.dealer_id 
        JOIN tCompany c ON d.company_id= c.company_id
        JOIN tContact E On e.contact_id = a.contact_id

        WHERE c.program_id = @program  
          And a.funded_date between @Beginning_Date and @Ending_Date
          Or a.cancel_refund_date between @Beginning_Date and @Ending_Date
    End 

    Exec spAdminFundedDate '05/01/2014', '05/30/2014','55'
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you need to handle the possible null values, and that should fix your issue.

Try something like:

```
isnull(a.cancel_refund_date, 0)
```

In your select statement. The 0 is what the value will be if it is null, so you can put whatever value that will fit your needs there. That will make it so no null values are pulled.

Comment: Yes, I was just starting to think about the isnull function. Thank you very much for your help! I will try to integrate it right now to see if it changes anything.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me understand more but did not solve my problem unfortunately.